# Symfony2 Config component, YAML doesnt understand PHP Magic constants

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to pass **DIR** as argument in my config like this

```
file_locator:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator
    arguments:  [__DIR__ . '/app/config']
```

but looks like this doesn't works, is there any possibility not to point full path in an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use php in yaml files. You should use the `kernel.root_dir` parameter if you want to ise an absolute path. That parameter contains the path to the dir with the `AppKernel`:

```
file_locator:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator
    arguments:  ['%kernel.root_dir%/app/config']
```

Comment: 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "kernel.root_dir"' :/ The problem might be because i am using symfony components, not full framework.

Comment: @Nerfair then you should create a container parameter which contains the root dir and use that instead

Comment: thank you! Solved this as 
    **$container->setParameter('app_root', __DIR__);**